# rake db:migrate issue duplicate but doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have tried `db:setup` `db:rollback` `db:drop` `db:migrate VERSION="0"` and practically everything I could think of, but I can't figure out this error. I even attempted to run it and drop the tables before initializing the create method. Even when I create a new one, like a products db, it's telling me that it's there but then it's telling me that it doesn't exist when I try to drop it. I've spent 2 days going through forums and videos to figure out what's occurring. This happens with both sqlite and mysql.

--Edited to include migrating Class--

```
class CreateTablenames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tablenames do |t|
      t.string :ID
      t.string :col1
      t.string :col2
      t.string :col3

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

--end edit

```
E:\RailsApplications\Blog>rake db:migrate
== 20151130191336 CreateTablenames: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:tablenames)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: ID: CREATE TABLE "tablenames" ("id
" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "ID" varchar, "col1" varchar, "col
2" varchar, "col3" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetim
e NOT NULL) E:/RailsApplications/Blog/db/migrate/20151130191336_create_tablename
s.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: ID
: CREATE TABLE "tablenames" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "I
D" varchar, "col1" varchar, "col2" varchar, "col3" varchar, "created_at" datetim
e NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
E:/RailsApplications/Blog/db/migrate/20151130191336_create_tablenames.rb:3:in `c
hange'
C:in `migrate'
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: ID
E:/RailsApplications/Blog/db/migrate/20151130191336_create_tablenames.rb:3:in `c
hange'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

E:\RailsApplications\Blog>rake db:migrate
== 20151130191336 CreateTablenames: migrating =================================
-- drop_table(:tablenames)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: tablenames: DROP TABLE "tablenames"E:/Rail
sApplications/Blog/db/migrate/20151130191336_create_tablenames.rb:3:in `change'
C:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: tablenames
: DROP TABLE "tablenames"
E:/RailsApplications/Blog/db/migrate/20151130191336_create_tablenames.rb:3:in `c
hange'
C:in `migrate'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: tablenames
E:/RailsApplications/Blog/db/migrate/20151130191336_create_tablenames.rb:3:in `c
hange'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Please include the troublesome migrations in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a table with two columns both called `id`:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: ID
: CREATE TABLE "tablenames" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "I
D" varchar, ...`

You have an `id` created by default by rails, and then you're trying to add another `ID` of type `varchar`.

You need to either rename your `ID` to something else, or you need to tell rails not to create its `id` column:

```
create table :tablenames, id: false do |t|
  t.string :ID
  ... rest of your migration
end
```

Ideally though, just remove your duplicate ID column and let Rails do its thing.

Comment: OH THANK YOU SO MUCH (where have you been and why aren't you teaching people lol) that immediately solved. I had no idea that rails defaultly creates id's although, now that I think of it, that makes sense.

Comment: If it solved your problem you should mark the answer as correct. Glad I could help.